# Adding a second legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to recreate this graph:

[image]

1) I've noticed a few of the actual data points on the graph are different sizes in my own. What is going on here?

2) How do I add that second legend, qsec?

Here is my current graph and code:

[image]

```
(gp3 <-ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=factor(cyl))) + geom_point(alpha = 0.5, size = 4.5) + geom_smooth(method = lm) + theme_light())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`qsec` is an another variable of the dataset `mtcars`. If you look closely, you see that on your first graph, the size of points is not a single value.

So, it looks like you have to pass `qsec` variable as a `size` argument in your `aes`:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, size = qsec, color=factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm) + 
  theme_light()
```

[image]